# Connection between roots and eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Why is there a relationship between the roots of a polynomial and the eigenvalues of the matrix representation?

---

Example 1:

**roots**

$$
u=a+ib\\
u^2=a^2-b^2+2iab\\
u^2=a(2ib+2a-a)-b^2\\
u^2=a(2u-a)-b^2\\
u^2-2au+a^2+b^2=0
$$

I call $u^2-2au+a^2+b^2=0$ the geometrically invariant polynomial. Its roots are $a\pm ib$. When multiplied together, they give $a^2+b^2$, the norm of a complex number.

**matrix**

$$
u=\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}\\
PuP^{-1}=\pmatrix{a-ib&0\\0&a+ib}
$$

---

Example 2: (here $u^2$ is the geometric product and $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices)

**roots**

$$
u=x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z\\
u^2=x^2+y^2+z^2
$$

The roots are $\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

**matrix**

$$
u = \pmatrix{z&x-iy\\x+iy&-z}\\
PuP^{-1}=\pmatrix{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}&0\\0& \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
$$

Comment: It's inconsistent to use "geometric product" and "Pauli matrices" at the same time. If $u=x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z$ is a matrix, then $u^2$ is the ordinary matrix product of $u$ with itself, which happens to be a scalar $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ multiple of the identity matrix. The geometric product applies to vectors, not matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).